# Swift: how to enable or disable multiple buttons embedded in custom classes at once?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uibutton, isenabled

Q: How do you enable multiple buttons when they are embedded inside custom cell classes?

**Working example**: Users are presented with a list of fruit to categorise. They select a banana and tap a colour category - in this case, yellow. Banana is added to the 'yellow' fruit list.

In this scenario, 'colour categories' are UICollectionView headers. The fruit are UICollectionView items. I'm trying to enable an 'Add Fruit' button (which is defined in a custom header cell class) when a user selects a fruit, for good user feedback.

However, I can't figure out how to bulk enable the buttons (within the headers) on selection. I first thought to create a variable on my *custom cell* which uses didSet() to enable the button, but I need to reload each UICollectionView header to set the variable, which I don't know how to do. I then created a variable on the collectionView itself which used reloadData(), but this removes the user's selected cells.

How do I get multiple buttons to enable at once, without resetting the entire collectionView?

Answer (score 1):

You can use IBOutletCollection. It provides connection to multiple outlets at once but similar kind of outlets, for eg. you need to connect multiple buttons or multiple labels.

Refer to this to understand IBOutletCollection

https://medium.com/@abhimuralidharan/what-is-an-iboutletcollection-in-ios-78cfbc4080a1